# How to calculate checksum (for DFPlayer mini)

Tags: checksum

For a while now I've been trying to calculate the checksum for my DFPlayer mini (which will still be delivered). Since I don't have that much experience with the subject, I don't really know how to do it, so I tried to help myself with the [data sheet](http://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/DFR0299-DFPlayer-Mini-Manual.pdf).
Unfortunately, this didn't bring me much and I started to search through forums. And that's when I came across the exact same question that was answered. But I was surprised that in [the example in the forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/mp3-tf-16p-aka-dfplayer-mini-another-cheap-sound-module/234530/19) a different checksum came out, than with the data sheet I found. A data sheet was attached to the forum contribution, which contains the same example but with different checksums (see pictures). [Example from (my) data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O9gm.png) ; [Example from the data sheet from the forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsNLw.png) ; [Forum post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYsx.png).

I have already tried to analyze the code of [the library which one could use](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobotDFPlayerMini) (but I do not want to use it if possible). But since I'm still a beginner, I couldn't rely on my results, partly because the same examples with the different checksums confuse me a lot.

I would be happy if someone could help me here

Comment: Those two data sheets seem to describe slightly different software versions, so besides documentation errors it might also be that the checksum computation is different. If you can observe a few correct messages, it should be possible to figure out which checksum computation is the right one for your device.

Answer (score 0):

most of the DFPlayer mini clones use this method:

```
/*
DFPlayer data frame format:
0      1    2    3    4    5   6   7     8     9-byte
START, VER, LEN, CMD, ACK, DH, DL, SUMH, SUML, END
       -------- checksum --------
*/

int16_t checksum = 0;

checksum = checksum - _dataBuffer[1] - _dataBuffer[2] - _dataBuffer[3] - _dataBuffer[4] - _dataBuffer[5] - _dataBuffer[6];

_dataBuffer[7] = checksum >> 8;
_dataBuffer[8] = checksum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's a possible answer for the checksum that I've used.

With some compilers, if you are trying to get an 16 bit answer using 8 bit variables, you need to "***upcast***" them to 16 bit values before doing the math.

Also, I don't like to subtract from 0, some compilers get squirrely with that and it makes it harder to read, so here's what I think is a better way to construct the DFplayer checksum

```
// Calculate the checksum (2 bytes)

unsigned int checksum = 1 + (0xFFFF-((unsigned int)Version_Byte + 
             (unsigned int) Command_Length +(unsigned int) CMD +
            (unsigned int) Acknowledge +(unsigned int) Par1 +(unsigned int) Par2));
```

Hope this helps somebody!